# Should I create traits to represent enum values for my models?

Tags: scala, slick

Say I have a model like:

```
case class User(
 id: Int,
 name: String,
 userType: Int)
```

Should I then do this:

```
sealed trait UserType
case object Member() extends UserType
case object Anonymous() extends UserType
```

I should also somehow associate a value for each UserType.

I would then change the User case class to have a UserType property instead of the int?

I guess then I would create a implicit converter for slick, which I believe would be a MappedColumnType from int to UserType.

**Update**
This is for using slick db access.

Comment: Repeat of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331528/scala-enumerations-case-objects-in-slick-good-practice

Answer (score 2):

I would do it the other way around. I would have a type for the user depending on the scenario that extends `User`:

```
sealed trait User
case class NormalUser(name: String, id: Int) extends User
case class SuperUser(name: String, id: Int, superPowers: Map[String, String]) extends User
```

And then pattern match on the actual `User` type when needed.

Comment: Sorry but this is slick specific, I will emphasis that beyond the slick tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with enum:

```
object UserType extends Enumeration {
  type UserType = Value

  val Member = Value("Member")
  val Anonymous = Value("Anonymous")
}
```

And the converter as you said:

```
implicit val userTypeColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[UserType, String](
  userType => userType.toString,
  UserType.withName
)
```

Then you can use `userType: UserType` in your `User` case class.
In table definition you can have `def userType = column[UserType]("user_type")`

**Update**
One of the reasons for choosing enum over trait is that slick is not able to find this implicit converter when you do not put the supertype explicitly.
E.g.

```
.filter(_.userType === Member)
```

yields

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Member.type
[error]  required: slick.lifted.Rep[?]
[error]       .filter(_.userType === Member).result
```

But the following works

```
.filter(_.userType === Member.asInstanceOf[UserType])

.filter(_.userType === (Member : UserType))
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Michal Tomanski mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204673/should-i-create-traits-to-represent-enum-values-for-my-models/42207368#42207368) - there are certain problems when using `trait` / `case object`s. What you would need to do is this:

```
 sealed trait UserType {
    val code: Int
  }
  case object Member extends UserType {
    override val code: Int = 0
  }
  case object Anonymous extends UserType {
    override val code: Int = 1
  }

  object UserType {
    def byId(id: Int): UserType = id match {
      case Member.code => Member
      case Anonymous.code => Anonymous
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("...")
    }
  }

  implicit val enumColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[UserType, Int](
    e => e.code,
    i => UserType.byId(i)
  )
```

Above would allow you to do query like this:

```
    UserTable
      .filter(_.userType === (Member :: UserType))
      .result
```

This is precisely what @Michal Tomanski pointed out. You can do small trick however to smoothen this up a little bit.

Just modify your trait like this:

```
  sealed trait UserType {
    val code: Int
    // I added field below
    val base: UserType = this
  }
```

and then you can have your query like this:

```
   UserTable
      .filter(_.userType === Member.base)
      .result
```

It may be slightly better alternative than casting.

Other than that - I'd follow @Michal Tomanski answer (using `Enumeration`) assuming that it is sufficient for your case (perhaps solution with `trait` / `case object`s is more flexible, but on the other hand there is more plumbing you need to do as can be seen in this answer).